# K8s newbe question: Getting minikube to run singularity-cri

Tags: kubernetes, singularity-container

I am making my first steps into k8s land in general and using k8s with Singularity in particular, so just  to be able to play around with the idea of Singularity as a service, I am trying to get Singularity-CRI to run under minkube, on my personal laptop (running Centos8 ).

I was able to install and setup sycri and kubelet, but I can't get minikube to use the cri. It seem to be able to run only with docker and some other preset drivers.

So did anyone manage to make minkube run over Singularity? Or maybe I should use another k8s implementation (I tried using sykube too, but it seem to be very unstable).

Many thanks,

Oren

Answer (score 0):

**Minikube** is probably not the best choice, considering the way it is implemented. It typically runs as a **VM** (different [drivers](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/) are available). There is also a [docker driver](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/docker/) which allows you to run **Minikube** in your existing docker environment, but it should be emphasized that it doesn't use your local docker as Container Runtime Environment, it runs the whole **Minikube** cluster as a container and it can come with different CREs inside e.g. you can select CRE different than Docker and still run it on Docker:

```
minikube start --container-runtime=cri-o --driver=docker
```

You can select **cri-o** but unfortunatelly you can not select **singularity**. As you can read [here](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/config/#runtime-configuration), currently the following **Container Runtimes** are supported:

> The default container runtime in minikube is Docker. You can select it
> explicitly by using:
>
> ```
> minikube start --container-runtime=docker
> ```
>
> Other options available are:
>
> - [containerd](https://github.com/containerd/containerd)
> - [cri-o](https://github.com/cri-o/cri-o)

You can always try setting up your **Minikube** with a different **Container Runtime** once it has been deployed and after:

```
minikube ssh
```

you can modify your environment and install [Singularity](https://sylabs.io/guides/3.0/user-guide/installation.html) and [Singularity-CRI](https://sylabs.io/guides/cri/1.0/user-guide/installation.html) inside your **Minikube VM** (or container if it runs as docker container) and [integrate it with your kubernetes cluster](https://sylabs.io/guides/cri/1.0/user-guide/k8s.html). Although it should be possible, I wouldn't recommend it at all. After first `minikube delete` your entire setup will gone, so it's definitely not meant to be used this way.

Somewhat more promising option seems to be running **Minikube** with [none (bare-metal) driver](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/none/). This should allow you configure it with your **Singularity** container runtime. But as you can read in docs, this option has some limitations and _ is recommended for advanced users only._ Well, integrating your **Minikube** with a different, not supported out of the box, container runtime seems like a good advanced use case, doesn't it ? So it's probably worth giving it a try.

Another, more recommended option, is to integrate it with kubernetes cluster set up with [kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/). I even found [an article](https://slateci.io/blog/kubernetes-with-singularity.html) which describes such integration step by step.

Comment: Difficult to say what can be the exact cause, but it doesn't look like anything CRE-specific. Could you post the entire error message in your question ?

Comment: Hi Mario, yes my priv comment was too general. But I made some progress since. Now I manage to get everything up but I have a problem with Calico. Some of the pods get stuck in a LoopState. I saw that this problem has to do with my NIC's setup. Do you have any good reference for that? Thanks. Oren.

Comment: Is it set up on some hypervisor e.g. Virtualbox ? Do your VMs have more than one NIC then ? Just check it's not NAT interface bo which Calico is bound.

Comment: OK pass that... Had a virb NIC configured by who knows what... had to ifconfig down. Now I have a problem with coredns certificate... I tried all kinds of soloutions that I found online but none works...

Comment: Please describe another problem in another Stack question. As soon as you have uncommon k8s setup, your question may look better on ServerFault.